# -2 reputation for question delete operation

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions, reputation-recalc

I don't understand well what's done:

Had a question removed, it had a vote balance level of 0
(guess 0+ and 0-)
and I see that:

[image]

that's why I'm a bit confused, if it had 1+, 1-, then it would have been -3 not -2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get +2 for accepting an answer on a question, as well as for having a suggested edit accepted. When a post has been deleted you lose those points again.

So, for the "Javascript for loop exluding keys" question, you got +2 points when you accepted the "Array.prototype.filter" answer, and you lost those 2 points again when the question was deleted. (The answer has no edit history, so the suggested edit option doesn't apply here).

As you point out in the comments, the other question was merged, forcing an automatic un-accept, leading to the same point loss.

Comment: thx for explanations, so actually it's more 2 unaccepts (the 2 are removed actually, the lower one is a merge with another question)

Comment: Note these are two different questions. I'm curious, because the question *does* have an accepted answer right now, and it says it was accepted on March 14 (and it's not the answer that's actually linked). Why would it randomly apply a -2 for an unaccept 8 months later? Although, [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9699639/timeline) says the question *doesn't* have an accepted answer...

Comment: yes the lower one, has been a merge, hence -2 also since I had an accepted answer also, the messages should be bother "unaccept"

Comment: ok thx Martijn, (but can't since it's merged with other answers and 1 is already accepted) thx for explanations

Comment: Right, didn't realize it was a merge, I don't think we can see that.